# Sharepoint 2010 SP2 and TFS 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, tfs

I've been searching with no luck to determine if there have been any issues with installing Sharepoint 2010 Service Pack 2 with Team Foundation Service 2010. Everything I have come across only mentions SP1:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2012/01/03/tfs-2010-what-service-packs-and-hotfixes-should-i-install.aspx

Does anyone know of any issues with installing SP2 with TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't see any issue with the SharePoint 2010 SP2 with TFS 2010, as MSFT msdn clearly mentioned that SP2010 required for the tfs 2010.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh667648(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh667648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But their is big advantage if you use the fresh ISO of SharePoint 2010 SP2( latest ISo, MSFT update couple of days ago), in this MSFT include windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We don't have a test tfs environment so wanted to have some folks weigh in. I don't think it should affect anything either but you never know. I saw the known issue about using custom xsl from the designer and so wanted to make sure the tfs addin stuff would still be ok.